# Handling Local Notifications when app is in background

Tags: ios, core-data, notifications

My app inserts an entry in Core Data when it receives local notifications.

This works fine in the following scenarios.

1. App is running and visible.
2. App is in background or not running at all, but when "View" is tapped on receiving notification.

But if I click on "Close", no entry is made. I've added the insert method in the "didReceiveLocalNotification" and "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" of the AppDelegate.

Can anybody elaborate on what method will be called if we close a notification?

Comment: You should try to choose tags that provide context for your question, and avoid overly broad tags that don't help to categorize the question.  I added the "osx" and "core-data" tags since you mentioned Core Data, and removed the "local" tag because there's little value in associating questions with each other on the basis that they mention the word "local".

Comment: The question mentions local notifications, which is why it ended up with the "local" tag.  This is an iOS question.

Comment: @Nicholas Riley: But look at the other questions tagged "local".  There's one about opening local HTML files in IE, one about running a local MySQL, one about X11 forwarding, etc. — no real correlation.

Comment: Sure, I'm just trying to explain why the question ended up with that tag; the person asking was probably unaware that tags can't contain spaces.

Comment: Since this is my first question on Stack Overflow, I wasn't aware about the usage of tags. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, tapping "Close" on a local notification will just close the notification and not call the app.

But can't you insert your data when you send the notification?

Comment: For business reasons, I need to make an entry only when the app receives a notification, and not when I send the notification

Comment: Do you send the notification with a delay?

Comment: Yes. The notification fire date is based on user input. It could be any time ranging from 1 hour to 1 month.

Comment: Could anyone even tell if I could at least capture the event when the notification was fired so that I could make my operations work when the notification is fired rather than tapping the "View" or "Close" button.

Comment: did you find any solution?